# How can we prevent admins pushing to a branch on GitHub without requiring reviews?

Tags: github

It used to be possible to protect a branch of GitHub and simply prevent pushing directly to that branch. Now, when configuring branch protections, there is a checkbox called "Require approvals" that can not be unselected if pull requests are required before merging:

[image]

How can we require a pull request (disable direct pushing to a branch) without requiring approvals? Our goal is to prevent accidental conflicts in the main branch, by enforcing the workflow that everyone (even administrators) should make a pull request to merge changes rather than committing directly.

Comment: Not sure if either of these is possible in GitHub, but in Azure DevOps, you can require a PR without a minimum number of approvers. (So you can create a PR and then just complete it.) Another option in AzDev is to set the minimum # of approvals to 1, and optionally allow the PR creator to approve their own PR and count as one of the approvers.

Comment: Note that *Git itself* is not actually involved in this: PRs, and approvals and branch controls, are all GitHub add-ons.

Answer (score -1):

I would imagine that the current solution you have in the screenshot would provide this?

If even admins of the repo need to submit PR's then that in turn means everyone needs to submit PR's, then requiring one approval wouldn't be an issue as the author of the PR can just approve it themselves before merging it? After checking the diff / automated builds for merge conflicts of course.

Answer (score -1):

Use the checklist only if you want additional features to your branch protection rule. What you seem to want is a protection rule without any of those additional features.

**Edit:** I saw in the title of this post that you wanted to include admins. Admins are by default not affected by these rules. But you can include them by checking `Include administrators` in that checklist of additional features.